# What happens when you send a non-state-changing transaction to the transaction pool

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, contract-invocation, evm

I understand that there are 2 endpoints for smart contracts. `Call()` for running view/pure function and `SendTransaction()` for state-changing transactions. Obviously a state-changing transaction sent to `Call()` would be reverted, but what happens in the inverse? Could the transaction still be mined and added to the chain? And can gas be consumed if gas was added?

Answer (score 1):

It works the same as any other transactions: You can call a view or pure function in a transaction, and the transaction can be mined as usual. It just won't do anything of course, since it's a view or pure function.

Comment: Just to add also that the gas has to be paid even if it's a view function

Comment: @Lauri Peltonen doesn't it only cost gas when it is called another contract and not a client?

Comment: If it's in a real transaction, it always costs gas, doesn't matter if there's another contract or not

Comment: Note that calls also use gas, in the same way as transactions, but you don't have to pay for it. Calls where the gas required goes over the block gas limit will not work.